# MongoDB start script - how does it choose configuration file?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I'm new to the MongoDB. I have the MongoDB server version 3.6.5 installed on my Xubuntu 14.04 VM, and I see it running (look at configuration file name):

```
ps -ef|grep mongodb
mongodb   79884      1  0 09:33 ?        00:00:44 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

However, the start script `/etc/init.d/mongodb` contains the following line:

```
CONF=/etc/mongodb.conf
```

I have both `mongodb.conf` and `mongod.conf` files in the `/etc` directory. I don't see where in the starting script the `mongodb.conf` configuration file got replaced by the `/etc/mongod.conf`.

Can somebody please explain mechanics of this replacement?

Comment: If you use command `ls -al /etc/mongod.conf` is there number 1 or 2 at second column? If it is 2, then those files are (i-node) linked, so it is an actually same file.

Comment: @JJussi - these two files (`mongodb.conf` and `mongod.conf`) have different size and content. It looks like the `mongodb.conf` was left there, because the MongoDB 2.* was installed on this VM before - but I'm note sure

Comment: `mongod` will use the config file that was assigned to it in the command line. How did you install MongoDB, and how did you start it? I think your guess is correct that the `mongodb.conf` file is from the older version.